# How to ban the usage of some specific functions, classes and header files in C++ project

Tags: c++, continuous-integration, embedded-linux, iostream

I'm trying to find a way how can I ban the usage of some functions, classes and header files in my C++ project.

More precisely, at my working project we try to avoid using C++ **iostream** library, because it hugely increases the binary size of our service. Instead, we try to use **stdio** library.

I would like to add an automatical verification that we don't use some header files (iostream...), classes (std::istream, std::ostream...) and functions (std::getline...) to our CI/CD pipeline.

Also there must be a way to ignore this verification for some directories (for example for 3d-party  libraries, tests and mocks) or, if it's possible, to ignore some separate lines.

Comment: Just have a script that parses files for "forbidden" includes at checkin and rejects the checkin (merge request or something similar) if it finds one of the includes in a file. 
I would not make it too difficult (e.g. have a list of forbidden files per component)

Comment: Instead of banning includes, why not do analysis of the executable/library size in a CI environment and look for any sudden jumps in size? It's not just an `#include` that can do this.

Comment: @PepijnKramer and @user17732522 I think both extremes are handable, depending on how much effort you are willing to put in. It should be fairly simple to write a script that `grep`s for forbidden keywords in (e.g.) a pre-commit hook or CI-job. Alternatively, you could use tooling like libclang to systematically check transitive includes or function calls. Either way, make sure the rules are transparent and simple. It's no fun to maintain software that is a pain in the *** to contribute to.

Comment: If you are REALLY committed, you could even write your own clang tidy checker that could automatically fix (some of) your offending code snippets, but that is definitely no simple task....

Comment: @joergbrech Yes, sure, libclang would work. That's a better suggestion.

Comment: Your make engine probably generates header dependency lists. If you enable the listing of standard headers then you can quickly parse these artefacts to detect unwanted headers as a build step. Downside: this will slow your build as make will then check for changes to the system headers which "never happens", but probably not by as much as your parser script, both of which will probably be negligable.

Comment: Another obnoxious way would be to declare a big enum inside the std namespace listing all the symbol names you dislike in one of you common headers. Any attempt to load an unwanted standard header will then lead to a name type collision at compile time.

Comment: @GemTaylor haha I love that last suggestion. Your co-workers will hate you dearly

Comment: @joergbrech I have done this sort of thing for my own use, but no, I wouldn't like to impose it on anyone else. Jamming ``enum ForceError { MyClassName};`` at the top of a cpp file is a great way to find out the include stack to your class when nothing else works.